# stripe payment issue-non-inr transactions in india should have shipping/billing address outside india

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, stripe-payments, strip

[image]

Hi i have integrated stripe payment in my developing application,

1)i choose country except india payment successes,

2)when i choose india i got error

**non-inr transactions in india should have shipping/billing address outside india. more info here:**

i have added my stripe redirect code

```js
const handlePaymentView = async (data = {}) => {
        const stripe = await window.Stripe('pk_test_xyz');
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            billingAddressCollection: "required",
            customerEmail: "test@gmail.com",
            items: [
                {
                    plan: planNameFindUrl(data),
                    quantity: 1
                }
            ],
            successUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/setting',
            cancelUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/setting',
        }).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result, "result");
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error, "errorerror");
        });
    };
```

Comment: you have created stripe account in india and asking payment from usd
Thats the reason

Comment: May I know is there anything wrong with the error message? It's doesn't appear to be code related and more likely Stripe policy related. Which means you should be writing to Stripe.

Comment: come in chat i will explain cause i have face same and will delete this question since it is not related to code

Comment: Hi @VishnuBhadoriya How to resolve this error,im stuck last 2 days

Comment: As mentioned, you should probably write directly to Stripe's support. But I would start by trying to make sure Checkout collects a shipping address by passing `shippingAddressCollection` (https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout#stripe_checkout_redirect_to_checkout-options-shippingAddressCollection) Alternatively, just do the payment in INR instead of USD(especially if you are not charging international customers).

Comment: You should be select Country United States then It will be work..!

Answer (score 1):

Just Use an Indian Stripe test card
India (IN)  4000003560000008    Visa

Answer (score 0):

Due to Indian Foreign policy, Stripe can't allow payment in Indian Rupees.

To solve,

1. Create a stripe account having USD as a handling currency
2. Register your Indian Business as Individual Proprietorship, Pvt Ltd or LLP. Then get verified in Stripe.

Now the transaction will work.

Comment: does that mean stipe will do payouts in USD to Indian bank?

Comment: Yes. Only if you have a registered business in India with a GSTIN.

Comment: And you need to verify your account in stripe. Create a new account with USD as primary currency.

Comment: I didn't know this approach, I do have GSTIN. Are there any drawbacks/gotchas before I start this process?

Comment: Nothing. Once you changed to USD, you can collect money from international users in their own currency and it will be deposited as INR. Second thing, you can't change the primary currency to a different one.

Comment: @Sakthitharan where to change USD can you explain me little bit?

Comment: Just when you create a new account in Stripe. Top Left corner, "+ new account" button